Android Kotlin - Google Credential Manager - get Access token
I'm using CredentialManager to sign in with google on android, the credentialMnager not give me the AccessToken to send it to my server to authenticate with app-secret and clinet-id
if (credential.type == GoogleIdTokenCredential.TYPE_GOOGLE_ID_TOKEN_CREDENTIAL) {
    try {

        val googleIdTokenCredential = GoogleIdTokenCredential
            .createFrom(credential.data)

        val idToken = googleIdTokenCredential.idToken
        val id = googleIdTokenCredential.id
        val displayName = googleIdTokenCredential.displayName
        val personPhoto = googleIdTokenCredential.profilePictureUri

    } catch (e: GoogleIdTokenParsingException) {
        Log.d("pikaboo", "Received an invalid google id token response", e)
    }
}

any one can help me how I get the AccessToken using this method or another

did you manage to get access token? because I have the same problem

kindly check my answer below

thx :) for your answer

I got the access Token using code below, I'm using jetpack compose, after getting api token and email,
call this function in viewmodel
viewModelScope.launch {
        val requestedScopes = listOf(
            Scope(Scopes.PROFILE),
            Scope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"),
            //Scope(Scopes.PLUS_ME),
           //Scope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.birthday.read"),
           //Scope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.gender.read"),
        )
        authorizationRequest = AuthorizationRequest.builder()
            .setRequestedScopes(requestedScopes)
            .requestOfflineAccess(SERVER_CLIENT_ID)
            .build()
            isAuthorizationRequest = true
    }

in view method
if (viewModel.isAuthorizationRequest && viewModel.authorizationRequest != null) {
Identity.getAuthorizationClient(context)
        .authorize(viewModel.authorizationRequest!!)
        .addOnSuccessListener { authorizationResult ->
            if (authorizationResult.hasResolution()) {
                authorizationResult.pendingIntent?.intentSender?.let { intentSender ->
                    authorizationLauncher.launch(
                        IntentSenderRequest.Builder(intentSender).build()
                    )
                }
                viewModel.updateIsAuthorizationRequest(false)
            } else {
                   viewModel.loginSocialApi("google", authorizationResult.accessToken ?: "")
                Log.i("accessToken", authorizationResult.accessToken ?: "")
                viewModel.updateIsAuthorizationRequest(false)
            }
        }
        .addOnFailureListener { e ->
            viewModel.updateIsAuthorizationRequest(false)
        }
}


@Composable
private fun rememberAuthorizationLauncher(context: Context, viewModel:LoginViewModel,) = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(contract = ActivityResultContracts.StartIntentSenderForResult()) { activityResult ->
if (activityResult.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
    val authorizationClient = Identity.getAuthorizationClient(context)
        .getAuthorizationResultFromIntent(activityResult.data)
    Log.i("accessToken", authorizationClient.accessToken ?: "")
    viewModel.loginSocialApi("google", authorizationClient.accessToken ?: "")
   }
}

